# Why does compiling this program without a main function result in "undefined reference to main"?

Tags: rust

I have this code below:

```
#![no_main]

pub mod struct_example {
    struct Pair {
        a: f64,
        b: f64,
    }

    pub fn example () {
        println!("##### Struct Example #####");
        let pair: Pair = Pair {a: 0.3, b: 0.4};
        println!("{} and {}", pair.a, pair.b);
    }
}
```

That I am trying to compile by issuing:

```
rustc src/structures.rs
```

What I get is the error below:

```
$ rustc src/structures.rs         
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-m64" "-L" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "./structures" "./structures.o" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-lmorestack" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcollections-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunicode-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librand-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-4e7c5e5c.rlib" "-L" "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-L" "/home/lowks/src/rust/gettingrusty/.rust/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "-L" "/home/lowks/src/rust/gettingrusty/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu" "-Wl,--whole-archive" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "-Wl,--no-whole-archive" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ldl" "-lpthread" "-lrt" "-lgcc_s" "-lpthread" "-lc" "-lm" "-lcompiler-rt"
note: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 22
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why is this? Is there something I am missing here ?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? If you want to make a library you don't need to provide a `main` function.

Comment: I just encountered an error when I tried compiling my library by the command `rustc <mylibrary.rs>` individually. What I learned now is that, if you wanted to build a library then just use `cargo build`. The question is does every rust code need a `main` method ? When does it know that it doe not need it ? Tested this by creating the easiest package I know and it seems when you try to compile a standalone file it will always error out if no main method is defined, or you can tell it not to do that with the no_main argument.

Comment: The `#![no_main]` feature is rather specialized. It's not something you commonly use. If you want an application, then write a `main` function. If you want a library, then don't write a `main` function. It's that simple.

Comment: If you're building a library crate, then I think `rustc` needs the `--crate-type=lib` option.

Comment: You can also specify in `Cargo.toml` that the crate is a library. By default, `cargo new` will create a library.

Answer (score 6):

By default, `rustc` produces a binary crate, not a library one, which needs a `main()`. You can pass `--crate-type=lib` if you're attempting to build a library instead of a binary.

Answer (score -4):

Okay I found it needs a top level `main` function like so:

```
pub mod struct_example {                                                                                                                                                                                     

    struct Pair {                                                                                                                                                                                            
        a: f64,                                                                                                                                                                                              
        b: f64,                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    pub fn example () {                                                                                                                                                                                      
        println!("##### Struct Example #####");                                                                                                                                                              
        let pair: Pair = Pair {a: 0.3, b: 0.4};                                                                                                                                                              
        println!("{} and {}", pair.a, pair.b);                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                        

}                                                                                                                                                                                                            

fn main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    println!("Hello world");                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```